# Windows 11 removed the "open containing folder" or "open file location" feature?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

After I updated my OS from Windows 10 to Windows 11, "open file location" disappeared from search result sometimes.

Sometimes, it shows me "open file location" like this so that I can open the containing folder.

[image]

But sometimes, it doesn't show me that. It just shows me "Copy path". It doesn't have "Open file location". This is very inconvenient. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> After I updated my OS from Windows 10 to Windows 11, "open file
> location" disappeared from search result sometimes.
>
> Sometimes, it shows me "open file location" like this so that I can
> open the containing folder.

This is how Windows 11 works.  Right Click and like operations are context sensitive.

So in your first screen shot, the selection was an App and the contexts provided are sensible for Apps.

In the second screen shot, the selection is a copy function because that is all that is sensible for a document. You already know where the document is located so "Open File Location" does not apply in most operations.

Windows 11 is full of context sensitive selections which vary on what you are trying to do.

What you see above is normal for Native Windows 11 as you have presented it.

Answer (score 1):

Open file location works only for shortcuts in your Start menu or
in your Quick Access recent files. It doesn't work at all for some
file types like `.exe` and others.

I have no idea why Microsoft decided on butchering that option,
but that only leaves you with the option of using a third-party
product.

[Everything by Voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/)
shows the file path and lets you navigate to the location via
right-click.
It's also free and far faster than the Windows search.